# Issue with reference value in ServiceNow

Tags: servicenow

I am very new to ServiceNow
I have two tables company and location.

location table has the column name.
company table has columns name and location. Here the location type is reference.

The company and location table data are below.

**Location**
Name
Chennai
HYD

**Company**
Name         Location
ABC            Chennai
CDE             HYD

My task is to query name and the location from Company table. The query as below.

```
var company = new GlideRecord('u_company');
subCat.query();

while (company.next()) {
   alert("Location: "  + company.location);
```

}

Here always the value is hexa decimal value. How can I get the actual text value for location?

Comment: Are you doing this in a _Client Script_ or in a server script such as a _Business Rule_? I'm guessing since your example has an `alert` it is on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing should be the `sys_id` of the `location` reference field.

If you're doing this in a **Business Rule**, you can pull this fairly easily using the [getRefRecord()](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/api_doc?v=jakarta&id=r_ScopedGlideElementGetRefRecord) method.

```
var company = new GlideRecord('u_company');
company.query();

while (company.next()) {
    var loc = company.location.getRefRecord()

    gs.log("Company Name: "  + company.getValue('name'));
    gs.log("Location Name: "  + loc.getValue('name'));
}
```

If you're doing this as a **Client Script**, it's a bit more involved but you can use [GlideAjax](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/script/server_scripting/reference/r_ExamplesOfAsynchronousGlideAjax.html). Take a look at the examples there, but here is a quick example.

Create a new *Script Include* that is Client Callable.

```
var MyCompanyUtils = Class.create();
MyCompanyUtils.prototype = Object.extendsObject(AbstractAjaxProcessor, {

    getLocationName : function() {
        // parameters
        var company = this.getParameter('sysparm_my_company');

        // query
        var rec = new GlideRecord('u_company');
        rec.addQuery('sys_id', company);
        rec.query();

        data = "Company not found."
        while (rec.next()) {
            var loc = rec.location.getRefRecord();
            data = loc.name;
        }

        return data;
    },

    type : "MyCompanyUtils"
});
```

Create a Client Script that calls this Script Include.

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading, isTemplate) {
    if (isLoading || newValue === '') {
        return;
    }
    // get the company referece value
    var company = g_form.getValue('company');

    var ga = new GlideAjax('MyCompanyUtils'); // call the object
    ga.addParam('sysparm_name', 'getLocationName'); // call the function
    ga.addParam('sysparm_my_company', company); // pass in company
    ga.getXML(showLocation);
}

function showLocation(response) {
    var answer = response.responseXML.documentElement.getAttribute("answer");

    alert("Location: " + answer);
}
```